# 11 wk old kittens

Tags: cats, behavior

[image]

My kittens are 11 weeks old, why do the suck on my blanket and try to take off with it?

Answer (score 0):

So suckling or "sucking", especially on soft or fuzzy things, is what kittens do for comfort. Suckling on their mom is a favorite pastime for them. You typically see suckling in kittens that were separated or weaned from Mom too early but that's not always the case. Your kittens feel safe doing this, especially if mom isn't around anymore or if she refused to let them suckle. I would gently try to deter them from this, it could lead to them doing this for a long time or to suckling on themselves, which can cause sores or drooly-wet bellies.